# Jersey Client API - POSTing InputStream

Tags: java, rest, jersey

What would be the best way to implement this:

My application allows users to upload an image, this is done via a RESTful service, encoded as "multipart/form-data”.

Now, in the body of the service, I don’t really need to save this file, but I want to use it to pass-into and invoke another service. So could I then use the Jersey Client API to make another call, without necessarily needing to save the file to disk, and then pass in the supposedly “temp” file.

Here is a bit of my code:

```
@Path("/file")
public class UploadFileService {

    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {

            //Given that I have ‘uploadedInputStream’ can I just pass this  
            //directly into the second call, below?

            ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
            Client client = Client.create(config);
            WebResource wr = client.resource(baseURI);
            ClientResponse response = wr.type("image/*")
                                        .entity(uploadedInputStream)   //legal??
                                        .post(ClientResponse.class);

    }
}
```

I’m guessing the alternative to the above, would be to temporarily save the file, and then pass in an instance of java.io.File into the entity() method. However, is it possible to get away with this?

Comment: InputStream is a contract for consuming bytes whereas OutputStream is for providing. In this case you would like to provide data for remote resource, so OutputStream should be used.

Comment: Naah. Depends on which perspective you choose. If I want to give you some data, *you* won't be so happy if I give you an `OutputStream`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, this should work. If it does not, file a bug at http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY